# Handlebars compile error

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js

I use handlebars to generate a tableview template like this:

**Template**

```
<div id="incidentTableView">
    <script id="incidentTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <th>Latitude</th>
            <th>Longitude</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {{#incidents}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{Latitude}}</td>
                <td>{{Longitude}}</td>
            </tr>
            {{/incidents}}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </script>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#incidentForm').submit(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var incidentLatitudeValue = $('#incidentLatitude').val();
       var incidentLongitudeValue = $('#incidentLongitude').val();

       $.post('ajax/test.php',
           {
           inputLatitude: incidentLatitudeValue,
           inputLongitude: incidentLongitudeValue
           },
           function(data){
               $('#incidentTableView').replaceWith($(this).createIncidentTableView(data));
           },
           "json");
   });

});

(function($){
    $.fn.createIncidentTableView = function(data){
        var source = $("#incidentTemplate").html();
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
        var context = {
            incidents: $.parseJSON(data)
        }
        return template(context);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

The script works fine on the first run. When I enter data into the form and hit the submit button the tableview appears smoothly showing data from the database.

When I then input other data and hit the submit button the second time, the following error occurs:

```
XHR finished loading: POST "http://api.url.com/public/ajax/test.php".
handlebars-v3.0.0.js:2381 Uncaught Error: You must pass a string or Handlebars AST to Handlebars.compile. You passed undefined
```

How does the #incidentTemplate corrupts the flow on the second attempt? Is there a way how I can make sure the compiling takes place when everything is loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does the #incidentTemplate corrupts the flow on the second
>   attempt?

Because after the first `post` you are replacing the template with the compiled html here:

```
 $('#incidentTableView').replaceWith($(this).createIncidentTableView(data));
```

Place your template somewhere outside of the `#incidentTableView` `div`.

Also, `replaceWith` will replace the current matched element so you'll be removing `#incidentTableView` from the DOM with the above code on the first `post`. You'll need that `div` to be around for subsequent `post`s so you'll want to do something like the following instead:

```
$('#incidentTableView').html($(this).createIncidentTableView(data));
```

Comment: Amazing... how obvious it seems now when I read it... Gosh... Thank you very much!!